# CSS-based loading image blocked by long UI-update loop

Tags: javascript, css

In my web app, I am showing a *loading* splash screen when making AJAX calls. The way I am doing this is:

1. The page has a `loadingScreen` div, which contains the splash screen image.
2. In CSS, `#loadingScreen` has `display:none`, while `body.loading #loadingScreen` has `display:block`.
3. Before an AJAX call, I add the `loading` class to `body` and in the `complete` function of the AJAX call, I remove the `loading` class.
4. I have 2 helper functions `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` which add/remove the `loading` class to/from the `body`

So far so good.

I also have some non-AJAX, UI-heavy operations such as `updateAllTableRows()` which reading the value of a text item on the page and update the text items in (all) 1000+ rows of a table with the value. I want to use the loading screen for this function as well.

**Approach 1 (Failed)**:
Add `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` to the top and bottom of updateAllTableRows().

```
function updateAllTableRows(){
  showLoading();
  <code to update the table>
  hideLoading();
}
```

This is not working. The loading screen is not shown, even though the helper functions are getting called (verified this using console.log statements in those functions).

**Approach 2 (Worked)**: Make the table update async by redefining the function

```
function updateAllTableRows(){
  showLoading();
  
  function innerUpdateFunction(){
    <code to update the table>
    hideLoading();
  }
  
  setTimeout(innerUpdateFunction, 10)
}
```

**My questions are**:

1. Why is the first approach not working? Does the browser read the class change (`loading`) and update the visibility of `#loadingScreen` in a separate thread, which is getting blocked by the execution of `updateAllTableRows()`?
2. **Approach 2** would require me to rewrite all of the other UI-heavy functions (redefine the inner function of move the code to the setTimeout block) instead of just adding calls to `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` at the start and end of the functions. Is this the right approach?

Comment: The browser does not automatically being the redraw phase of the page when it is changed by javascript.  It must be given a chance to do so.  So long as your javascript is continually processing operations, the browser will not be given a chance to do graphical work.  Where as, when you use the setTimeout, it briefly gives up control to allow the browser to do any other work needed to be done.  Thus you see the loading thing show up.

Comment: You have not supplied sufficient code for us to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Are you referring to the _<code to update the table>_ part? That's just a bunch of jquery to read and update values in the table. e.g. `$('#tableID .rowClass.editable .textInput').val(valueFromAnotherInput)`. I left that out because I am not trying to understand why this chunk of code is taking time. I was trying to understand why this chunk of code is blocking the visibility effects of `showLoading()` on `#loadingScreen`. Taplar's comment points me in that direction.

Comment: @Taplar Is there some documentation that I can read about this? For now, I'm gonna look at this: https://blog.usejournal.com/what-the-heck-is-repaint-and-reflow-in-the-browser-b2d0fb980c08